# Enqueue's functionality needed in WPF Test automation project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, silverlight

I was used these methods `EnqueueConditional, EnqueueCallback, EnqueueDelay` in my earlier silverlight test automation project using Silverlight Toolkit long back. How can I get the similar  behavior of the methods in WPF Test automation project? Is there Microsoft WPF toolkit or any other toolkit which comes supportability for WPF application with the same behavior or functionality of Enqueue's of Silverlight.

Comment: **WPF** has more features, than **Silverlight**.  So I suggest you to use `EnqueueConditional, EnqueueCallback, EnqueueDelay` methods from namespace `SilverlightTest` in your WPF application.